# Issue when creating CIImage from file

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

I get a nil no matter what I try to load a `CIImage` directly from file. However I can load the file into a `UIImage` and convert that to `CIImage`.

So, this works:

```
        let testUIImage = UIImage(named: "image_0001.jpg")!
        let testCIImage = CIImage(image: testUIImage)  // OK
```

but this doesn't:

```
        let testCIImage = CIImage(contentsOf: URL(string: "image_0001.jpg")!)  // returns nil
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the URL?

Comment: URL should convey the location of the image not the image name itself

Comment: `UIImage(named: "")` is a shortcut for looking for images in the assets folder. `URL(string: "image_0001.jpg")` is not a valid URL and doesn't point to the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `UIImage(named: "name.ext")` is a convenience initializer. It's a short form of

   ```
   guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"name", withExtension:"ext"),
         let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
         let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
   return image
   ```
2. `URL(string:` expects a string representing a **full** URL starting with a scheme for example

   ```
   URL(string: "https://example.com/path/to/image_0001.jpg")
   ```

   or

   ```
   URL(string: "file:///Users/myuser/path/to/image_0001.jpg")
   ```

Comment: thanks, your answer solves it. I was just giving the wrong URL. The image is in the file system, added to the project with "Location: Relative to group" (I just dragged & dropped from the file manager). To make the URL valid I not only had to add 'file:///", but also I had to enter the full absolute path: "file:///image_0001.jpg" didn't work, which to me is incomprehensible because  UIImage(named: "image_0001.jpg") works.

Answer (score 5):

you need to give file url  if your image inside main bundle then you can get url like below code

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"image_0001", withExtension:"jpg") else {
  return 
}
let testCIImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url)
```

Comment: this one works too, thanks. I'd like to accept BOTH yours and @vadian's answers, because they are both correct but apparently I can't. I'm a noob for swift and frankly I didn't get your answer at first, but I immediately understood vadian's so he gets the tick.